# No review, only hats

Tags: bug, top-bar, winter-bash, responsive-design

I can’t see the review or help icon in the top bar. All I see is hats and some other stuff:

[image]

The help icon is typically missing for me when I unlock review. But it’s blocked by hats even on sites where I don’t have review unlocked.

This is happening on my tiny phone in portrait (the only layout I use) and you can reproduce it with a sufficiently narrow browser window on a pc too.

Comment: This may be intentional but if it's not, we won't be able to fix it until the last day of Winter Bash.

Comment: I thought the question title was a request :(

Answer (score 8):

There is some [work underway with the mobile UI](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1076979773082124289?s=20), if I reduce my *experience* to the mobile view I see even less:

[image: Top Bar]

If you are already in desktop mode (on your browser) uncheck that (in your browser's menu) and choose the "Mobile" link near the bottom of the webpage:

[image: Enable Mobile View]

Now choose "Full Site" from the link in the footer:

[image: Full Site Link]

Now in your browser's menu re-enable the "Request Desktop Site" checkbox and you should end up with this view on a mobile phone using the Firefox browser for Android in portrait mode:

[image: Full Site - Desktop Mode - Topbar]

Don't forget to disable the sidebar in your site settings preferences if necessary:

[image: Preferences - Hide Left Navigation]

That ought to provide the best view available on mobile if you want to see everything, on an old phone with an especially narrow portrait mode view everything may not fit.

The CSS is also not correct for the newest phones, notice that my reputation for the site doesn't show up - I mentioned that long ago to Tyler, so it's in the Job Jar.

Comment: I know how to get to landscape and it only involves turning off rotation lock. The problem is I don’t get to see very much content in landscape especially since if I’m typing I can only see the keyboard and a tiny sliver of what I’m typing. That’s why I have rotation locked. I use an iPhone SE and it’s so tiny that I don’t have a left nav option: I never see it because the screen is so small.

Comment: My answer is for portrait mode, which is preferable for use on a mobile phone. The same advice works for landscape mode - so you're good either way. As for iPhone specific answers only, you should add a tag for that.

Comment: @Laurel What I'd do in this situation is turn off rotation lock, go to landscape mode just long enough to see the review menu and select it, then rotate back to portrait after the review page loads. It's not awesome but it's something.

Answer (score 4):

Part of the top bar now scrolls so I don’t see this being a problem when hats come back. (Seeing as I had the same problem with the help icon being hidden instead of review after hats were gone, which this fixed.) Here’s a screenshot of the top scrolled a little:

[image: screenshot]

(With a small browser window you can do this on desktop too, by dragging the very bottom of the top bar.)

It’s not particularly obvious that it scrolls, but that’s a different issue.

Comment: I see a winter hat coming for those who figure out one can scroll...