# Can you spot the scrollbar?

Tags: bug, design, top-bar, responsive-design, scrolling

With the winterbash Icon present a scrollbar is introduced on small screensizes. Can you spot it? [image]

Comment: It's been this way for a while, if you have a small enough screen. [Called it, back in 2019](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337684/323179) (when there was no visible scrollbar).

Comment: Related: [The top bar is a little too full for moderators on mobile](/q/344750/289905) and [What's this weird black line on the topbar of a site I moderate?](/q/369773/289905).

Comment: @Laurel agreed, but the scrollbar should be a bit more obvious.